# Open Android TV app on top of TV channels simultanuously

Tags: android, overlay, android-tv

I want to open my Android TV app while user watches the usual TV program. Basically the app will be sown as a simple dialog or overlay on top of TV channels. I will be making sure not to disturb the TV watching experience.

Does the Android TV API supports this feature? Any leads for me?